# Script injection from outside the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, code-injection

I need to know how some softwares or programs inject html,css,js into webbrowser without installing any extension. once I open chrome or firefox I find ads on google homepage, facebook, youtube ... I need to know how they inject this, how to prevent it and how to know which program did it.

Here is my google home page on chrome

[image]

and all the extensions are disabled I even deleted most of them

[image]

What worries me the most, is that in google chrome devtool (ressources) the url of the displayed image is the same url of the google logo. when I enter this url I found the real logo of google

[image]

Comment: What operating system are you running? Are you sure, your system isn't otherwise compromised?

Comment: windows 8 and it's not compromised. I'm going to scan my computer to delete viruses but I want to know how this code injected from outside the browser. is this really possible ?

Comment: check your add remove program in control panel, there would be addon application install.. I got same issue earlier

Answer (score 2):

You have a computer virus somewhere affecting you.

Edit:

Multiple things could be happening:

1. Something is intercepting the network request and injecting a different image.
2. Something has replace your version of chrome with their own version. The base code is public and their version can do whatever they want.

Comment: The question is asking how the virus is doing that and what can be done about it.

Comment: I know that it's not google, I need to know how this virus injects code from outside the browser

Comment: It can be doing this various ways.

#1. Intercept the network request and inject a different image instead.
#2. Replace your version of chrome with their own version because base code is public. Their version can do whatever they want.

Answer (score 1):

keep in mind, that content de-facing might happen on the Router/Proxy level, too.
some routers have content filters and domain blacklists for child protection.
maybe it's some kind of joke on the router level, where someone added
a content replace filter.

- check your computer (spybot + kaspersky)
- check your router
- check firewall and all networking filters in the chain